# Linear Algebra - $A$ a subspace of $R^3$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Is $A = \{(x,y,z) | x = 3y,z = -y\}$ a subspace of $R^3$

I know that $A$ contains a zero vector and in addition, it is closed under addition and scalar multiplication.

Could someone explain how I would show this is a mathematical proof?

Comment: Thats all you need to show. Its a well known theorem in linear algebra that a non-empty subset of a vector space (which you've shown, by noting it contains the zero vector) closed under vector addition and scalar multiplication is a subspace. This is sometimes called the (two-step) subspace test: http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Two-Step_Vector_Subspace_Test. Your linear algebra text probably has a similar statement and proof.

Answer (score 0):

*Hint* You can write any vector in $A$ as $(3y,y,-y)=y(3,1,-1)$ with $y\in\Bbb R$. It follows your set $A$ is the set of $\Bbb R$-multiples of a *fixed* vector $\bf v$, i.e. it is of the from $\langle {\bf v}\rangle=\{\lambda {\bf v}:\lambda \in\Bbb R\}$. Can you show such kind of subset of $\Bbb R^3$ is *always* a subspace, regardless of what ${\bf v}$ we pick?

For example, ${\bf 0}\in\langle {\bf v}\rangle$ since $0\cdot {\bf v}={\bf 0}$.

Comment: Yeah, I figured that out, but I don't understand what to do after that :/

Comment: @Shanel What about now?

Comment: To be honest, I think that since it contains a zero vector, i could show that $(3, 1, -1) * 0$ = $0$ therefore, its a subspace, right?